# Nested similar route in vue-router not rendering deep level components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component that renders a list of buttons from the children of a route.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="childrenRoute.length" class="buttons">
       // render buttons
    </div>
    <transition v-else name="fade" :name="transitionName" mode="out-in">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
</template>
```

When URL changes, it's not rendering the component of the matched route, instead updating the same component.

`/clients/:id`
[image: First level route]

`/clients/:id/second-level`
[image: Second level route]

`/clients/:id/second-level/third-level`
[image: Third level route]

But when I reload the page, it renders correctly.

[image: Correct]

Any thoughts?

Comment: should it be this.$childrenRoute.length ?

Comment: `childrenRoute` is a computed property, gives an array of actual routes list with no Vue bindings.